How to retain pasted format in the Text Area with reactQuill
When typing/pasting a text with specific formatting inside the message modal, the formatting is not saved for the next time the message modal is opened.
When closing the message modal, the system should 'remember' the formatting used in the previous message.
So I've tried this first. in this version it does remember the typed / pasted text but not the format. after reopening the modal it forgets the format and removes all the spaces which makes it 1 alinea of text instead of let's say 4 alinea's.

export interface TextAreaProps {
readonly value: string
readonly onChange: (val: string) => void } export default function TextArea(props: TextAreaProps) {

return (
    <div className={styles.root} id="textArea">
        <ReactQuill
            className={styles.textArea}
            theme='snow'
            defaultValue={props.value}
            onChange={(val) => props.onChange(val)}
            modules={modules}
            formats={formats}
        />
    </div>
)

}
another solution I tried was to implement this:
    const [content, setContent] = useState<string>('');

useEffect(() => {
    const storedContent = localStorage.getItem('messageContent');
    if (storedContent) {
        setContent(storedContent);
    }
}, []);

const handleChange = (val: string) => {
    setContent(val);
    props.onChange(val);
};

const handleClose = () => {
    localStorage.setItem('messageContent', content);
}

return (
    <div className={styles.root} id="textArea">
        <ReactQuill
            className={styles.textArea}
            theme='snow'
            value={content}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleClose}
            modules={modules}
            formats={formats}
        />
    </div>
)

}
But in this version. it does remember the format when reopening the modal. but for every user and every textarea in every category.

Please don't post images of code.
